# Display equations in a WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, math, equation

I know this is a duplicate, but all other similar questions I have found are quite old and most accepted answers are outdated or dead links.

I would like to display equations in WPF in a good looking way, if possible without going through generating images. For example having a simple control that I add to my WPF app that would let me add the equation through MathML or Tex formatting.

Since with Windows 7 Microsoft integrated a very nice equation drawing capability (Math Input Panel) and also has several tools that can display nice looking equations (Word and MS Mathematics), I'm very surprised that there is no way to easily display an equation in WPF.

Is there any way to leverage one of those tool for the display?

I'm not trying to edit it, or let the user modify it, but simply display an equation.

Actually, for now, even subscripting or superscripting would be quite useful. I've tried using the Typography.Variants property, but it works only if I choose the font "Palatino Linotype".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There exists this [WPFMath](https://github.com/ForNeVeR/wpf-math) library (also available on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WpfMath/)) that allows to render LaTeX formulas in a WPF control.

Usage would be:

```xml
<Window ... xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:WpfMath.Controls;assembly=WpfMath">
    <controls:FormulaControl Formula="\left(x^2 + 2 \cdot x + 2\right) = 0" />
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you dont want to generate images but this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11406/Enable-Your-Users-to-Write-Math-Equations-in-Your) may still be useful for you. It shows how to use MimeTex to take a Tex formatted equation, generate a gif and display it. The example is in winforms but if you can generate the equation it is easy to display in wpf.

Comment: Well, WPF being all about vector graphics, putting an important element of the UI in GIF makes me kind of uncomfortable. It will also probably break the resizing possibility.